# mapreduce program

Tags: mapreduce

Consider one .txt file.. in that i have no of paragraphs separated by a new line character. 

 Now i need to count the no of words in each paragraph.. Consider the  counted words as a key in
the mapper and assign a value 1 initially for all  
   And in Reducer give me a sorted output  
Please give me a complete code for better understanding, Because I am a fresher  

And please give me better clarification in how it counts the no of words in each paragraph

Comment: what all you have tried so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapper doing the counting would not yield you the performance that you are trying to achieve through the map reduce technique.

To really utilise the benefit of map reduce, you should consider treating the paragraph number 
(1 for the 1st paragraph, 2 for the 2nd and so on) and then sending these paragraphs for individual counting to different reducers running on different nodes (harnesses the capability of parallel processing) and then to sort the output you may feed it into a simple program to do the sorting for you, or if the number of paragraphs is large, feeding this into another map reduce job. In that case, you would need to consider a range of numbers as the key for map reduce, say numbers (count of words in the paragraph obtained from the previous map reduce job) from 1 to 10 should fall into one bucket and should be mapped to one key, and then the individual reducers can work on these individual buckets to sort them, and the result can be collated in the end to get the complete sorted output.

An example implementation of map-reduce can be found at : http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply dude... However i asked abt how to count the words in each paragraph in a single file.. Now i know the Concept.. !st split by space and us str.length.. U can acheive this... Anyway thanks for us info...